# Show that $a+b+c=0$ implies that $32(a^4+b^4+c^4)$ is a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, symmetric-polynomials

There are given integers $a, b, c$ satysfaying $a+b+c=0$. Show that $32(a^4+b^4+c^4)$ is a perfect square.

EDIT: I found solution by symmetric polynomials, which is posted below.

Comment: Guessing the form this square (I have no idea how it can look) and expressing $(a+b+c)^4$ in elementary symmetric polynomials (this form makes cancelation easier). I posted it also because I would prefer to see some more systematic approach (even if I will find out it by myself, it will just a guess). I know that from that condition I can obtain many identities easily, but I don't know which I should use here. Perhaps at first it will be better to just see some hint.

Comment: +1 for your solution, you should consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will do as you suggest.

Answer (score 13):

It suffices to show that $2(a^4+b^4+c^4)$ is a perfect square.

\begin{align}
& 2(a^4+b^4+c^4) \\
=& 2((b+c)^4+b^4+c^4) \\
=& 2(2b^4+4b^3c+6b^2c^2+4bc^3+2c^4) \\
=& 4(b^4+\bbox[2px, border:1px solid]{2b^3c}+\bbox[2px, border:1px dashed]{3b^2c^2}+2bc^3+c^4) \\
=& 4((b^4+\bbox[2px, border:1px solid]{b^3c}+\bbox[2px, border:1px dashed]{b^2c^2})+(\bbox[2px, border:1px solid]{b^3c}+\bbox[2px, border:1px dashed]{b^2c^2}+bc^3)+(\bbox[2px, border:1px dashed]{b^2c^2}+bc^3+c^4)) \\
=& 2^2 (b^2(b^2+bc+c^2)+bc(b^2+bc+c^2)+c^2(b^2+bc+c^2))\\
=& 2^2(b^2+bc+c^2)^2
\end{align}

Comment: Nice and quick, thank you very much.

Comment: @Shingle You're welcome.

Answer (score 7):

Although I find solution given by GNU Supporter definitely more straightforward and elementary than mine, I will place what I found after asking the question, because it might give another perspective and some idea about what one can do when can't recognize correct formula.

Let $l_i$ denote elementary symmetric polynomial of degree $i$ and $s_i$ power symmetric polynomial of degree i. We need to show that $l_1=s_1=0$ implies that $32s_4$ is a perfect square. By Newton's Identity (but in case of three variables it can be easily checked by hand) $s_4=s_3l_1-s_2l_2+s_1l_3$ and $s_2=s_1^2-2l_2$, which by assumption takes form $s_4=-s_2l_2=-(s_1^2-2l_2)l_2=(-l_2)(-2l_2)=2l_2^2$ and from this $32s_4=64l_2^2=(8l_2)^2$.

Comment: +1 for exploiting the symmetry to the end. `in case of three variables it can be easily checked by hand` I took the liberty to post a variation on that idea as a separate answer, since it may be instructive on its own for those less familiar with Newton's identities.

Answer (score 5):

> EDIT: I found solution by symmetric polynomials (in variables a, b, c)

The following more or less transcribes OP's solution in direct calculations, without explicitly using [Newton's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities#Formulation_in_terms_of_symmetric_polynomials). From the assumption that $a+b+c=0\,$:

$$
0 = (a+b+c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2 + 2(ab+bc+ca)
$$

$$
 \implies 2(ab+bc+ca)=-(a^2+b^2+c^2) \tag{1}
$$

$$
\require{cancel}
(ab+bc+ca)^2 = a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2 + \cancel{2abc(a+b+c) } \tag{2}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
a^4+b^4+c^4 & = (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2) \\[5px]
 & \overset{(1),(2)}{=} 4(ab+bc+ca)^2 - 2(ab+bc+ca)^2 \\
 & = 2 (ab+bc+ca)^2
\end{align}
$$

The latter gives $32(a^4+b^4+c^4)=\big(8 (ab+bc+ca)\big)^2\,$.

Comment: +1, this shows directly how symmetric polynomial identities (which to me seem a little bit abstract) give "exact" formula results (I didn't expected that this translation can be done in so nice way)